# What is the difference between 群 and 羣?

Tags: word-choice, difference

As titled. They seem to be made up of the same two components: 羊 and 君. As such, are they interchangeable? Or do they have different usage regardless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[羣](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/js/7FA3.htm) is an archaic variant of [群](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/js/7FA4.htm). That is, although they mean the same thing, you would use 群 nowadays.

Interestingly, 羣 appears to have been the "correct" version in the past, and at some point 群 took that place:

- There is a [Three Kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms) politician by the name of [陳羣](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_Qun), whereas the identically named [Republican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_China_(1912%E2%80%9349)) politician [陳群](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E9%99%88%E7%BE%A4_(%E6%B0%91%E5%9B%BD)), use different characters in the last name.
- [The Kangxi dictionary entry for 群](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/kx/7FA4.htm) states that it is a "vulgar variant" (《五經文字》羣，俗作群。), so the transition was at least between Qing and Republic of China.

Answer (score 3):

This is [异体字(variant Chinese character)](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%82%E4%BD%93%E5%AD%97).

Their meaning and pronunciation are same, only different in shape.

In this case, `群` is most orthodox and known as orthodox characters(`正字`), `羣` is the `异体字`,

Answer (score 1):

Both the same.  群 is more pleasing in shape and 羣 is more difficult to write to fit into the square space.